# How to use Serilog with Amazons OpenSearch?

Tags: logging, serilog, opensearch

Can we already use Serilog with Amazons OpenSearch?

I've tried this using the ElasticSearch Sink:

```
var log = new LoggerConfiguration()
                  .WriteTo.Console()
                  .WriteTo.Elasticsearch(new ElasticsearchSinkOptions(new Uri("http://url:9200"))
                  {
                      AutoRegisterTemplate = true,
                      FailureCallback = FailureCallback,
                      EmitEventFailure = EmitEventFailureHandling.RaiseCallback | EmitEventFailureHandling.ThrowException
                  })
                  .CreateLogger();

        log.Information("Hello, Serilog!");

        Log.CloseAndFlush();
```

which doesn't seem to work.
The exception on the FailureCallback is null so I don't even get a real error message.

Comment: Hey I guess your code worked to log data in AWS OpenSearch. Can you pls share the full code?

Comment: Please be aware that as of version 9.0.0 of Serilog.Sinks.Elasticsearch, integration with OpenSearch is removed (https://github.com/serilog-contrib/serilog-sinks-elasticsearch). There is a Serilog.Sinks.OpenSearch package which should provide the functionality you want, and looks to be broadly binary-compatible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can see that you are trying to connect using HTTP protocol, so I assume that you're attempting to run some tests on the local environment, but did you disable the OpenSearch security plugin (it requires you to use SSL and authorize yourself)?
If not you gotta do this first: https://opensearch.org/docs/latest/security-plugin/configuration/disable/

Keep in mind that disabling security is an absolute no-go for production environments.

Answer (score 0):

Tried Serilog.Sinks.Elasticsearch with the exact same configuration and it works for me.

Do you get an error in opensearch logs?
What minimum log level are you using for the sink? Your log goes to information but I believe the default for serilog is warning

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead).

Comment: @Tyler2P those are the rules but I don't see any harm done in this case. At least OP is trying to help.